# Installing Vue-cli issues

Tags: node.js, vue-cli

I am trying to install vue-cli with npm using 'npm install -g vue-cli' command. I am constantly getting this error in console

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyVeR.png)

I also have tried to manually add js-beautify to the the node_modules folder but I still get the same error message.
Any idea what should I do?

Comment: It looks like an issue with js-beautify v1.7: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1247. Try `npm install js-beautify@1.6.14`

Comment: I guess, your `node.js` is outdated => `6.11.3`, Please try installing a recent version and try executing the same command again.